# WIX showing Dialog conditionally - FileSearch

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to show or skip **boraDlg** dialog page in WIX according to a variable
**CHROMEEXISTS** variable should have true or false if the file exists

but in both using util:FileSearch or DirectorySearch & FileSearch, it didnt' work.

In to log I always see this :

```
AppSearch: Property: CHROMEEXISTS, Signature: CheckFileDir
MSI (c) (A4:BC) [09:27:05:532]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
MSI (c) (A4:BC) [09:27:05:532]: Note: 1: 1322 2:  
Action ended 9:27:05: AppSearch. Return value 1.
```

How can I do that?

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Fragment>
    <!--util:FileSearch Id="CHROMESearch"
                     Variable="CHROMEEXISTS"
                     Result="exists"
                     Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"/-->
     <Property Id="CHROMEEXISTS">
      <DirectorySearch Id="CheckFileDir" Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]Google\Chrome\Application123\" AssignToProperty="yes">
        <FileSearch Id="CheckFile" Name="chrome.exe" />
      </DirectorySearch>
    </Property>

    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR"></Property>
    <UI Id="JpUI">
        <Dialog Id="boraDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlg_Title)">
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" >
                    <Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="Update">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.LicenseAgreementDlgBannerBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="340" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="CNET Changelog" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Version 3.0" />
                <Control Id="LicenseText" Type="Text" X="20" Y="60" Width="330" Height="140"  Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Please export your database and delete files" />
            </Dialog>
            
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"></UIRef>
      <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="boraDlg" Order="3">NOT CHROMEEXISTS</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="3">CHROMEEXISTS</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="boraDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="3">NOT Installed</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="boraDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="3">NOT Installed</Publish>
      <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="3">NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```